# How to display constant variables or macros in documentation

Tags: c, doxygen

Is it possible to use the value of a constant variable or a macro in the doxygen documentation?

I have the following lines in the source file

```
#define RD_IDN 0x01
#define RD_TEMP 0x02
// etc
```

and I'd like to use these values somewhere else in the documentation like this:

```
/* If the received command code is 0x01, the device will return it's unique ID. */
```

Comment: Why not `/* If the received command code is RD_IDN , the device will return it's unique ID. */`? If the constant value ever changes for whatever reason, the documentation keeps telling the truth.

Comment: Because this is harder to read/understand

Comment: They why bother naming the constant at all if it's "harder to read/understand". Use `0x01` everywhere.

Comment: Because the values might change and then I have to manually change all the numbers in the documentation^^

Comment: If you write something like `/*! If the received command code is #RD_IDN, the device...*/` at least Doxygen will put a link to the macro definition (you must use `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING`). If you add a description to the macro definition, the browser will show it (the hint, not the value) as hint when you hover the mouse.

Comment: Are `/**` or `/*!` not working for documenting?

Comment: @Giovanni thanks for the tipp. That might be an alternative if it's really not possible

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible to do it. The features of the doxygen's built-in C-preprocessor are described in the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/preprocessing.html), and there is nothing about replacement of macros in the comments.

As alternative, you may try something like

```
//! Your RD_IDN description
#define RD_IDN 0x01
#define RD_TEMP 0x02
```

and then

```
/*! If the received command code is #RD_IDN, the device will return it's unique ID. */
```

Doxygen will add a link to the macro, with `Your RD_IDN description` shown ad hint when you hover the mouse. To see the value, you still have to click on it. Note that you must keep `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` set to the default value `YES` on you Doxyfile.